# Building apk for expo project

Tags: react-native, build, expo, apk

I convert my expo project to apk, but after building successfully, when I click in the link generated by expo to download the apk, I get this error below

Hmmm… can't reach this page The connection was reset.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Please help me if possible because it tried so many times.

I tried to use was build -p android --profile preview.

I installed react native 0.72.3 and expo 49.0.7, sdk 49, node 18.17.0
I expect to download the APK and I test it on my Android phone, but failed to download.

Comment: Have you tried going to the website expo.dev, check your build there and click on the button "download" ?

Comment: Yes, i have gone there, but when i click download but, i get this error

"This site can’t be reachedThe connection was reset.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
Running Windows Network Diagnostics
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET"

I don't know why